# Wireshark. I think my webserver is being abused with malicious injection. Can I have a second opinion?

Tags: nginx, wireshark

I think my webserver is being abused with malicious injection, which is resulting in multiple 400 Bad Requests and 414 URI error codes.

I can see from the packet analysis an IP is sending erroneous data to my webserver, similar to the below (but with multiple attempts):

### .../././././././ 0050 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f ././././././././ 0060 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f ././././././././ 0070 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f ././././././././ 0080 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f ././././././././ 0090 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f ././././././././ 00a0 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f 2e 2f ././././././././

In some cases the packet analysis reveals that file paths are included in the submitted PSH,ACK packet, suggesting an attempt to access back end file and config data. In all cases, the server is responding 400, and 414 error codes for larger (1441+ bytes) packet sizes. I am certain that this activity is malicious, and likely to be either an attempt to inject data to DoS the webserver, or an attempt to gain unauthorised access to server files.

Would someone able to help with validating or advising on my analysis?

Comment: Welcome Andy!

Without having true knowledge of this situation, i figured i mentionned that there are many many odditties in the humongous pool of ways to browse/access web services nowadays. As i have no clue about this specifically, i can't help. Worth noting that there are some very weird solutions to even weirder problems that come from developpers of software intended to interact with the even weirder, bigger, sketchier etnicity of web services available.

Thanks, have fun!

Comment: This is not something that can be answered with a single answer on Stack Overflow. If you are worried, I would hire a security consultant.

Answer (score 0):

What are the NGINX access-log is telling you about that? Are those requestes are send against your http interfaces?

If you think this one IP is misbehaving in some sort block it with IP-Tables or even with NGINX directly and check the log again. Try to update the post with an actual log entry but at this point for me it looks like some possible ussage of a file traversal attack. But check the logs and if you think the attack is comming from a single IP, block it